# How does one add or link an iTunesAccount account to someone else's Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My situation:

I have an iTunesConnect account, associated with *MyCompany Ltd*. I also the the same login for my Apple Developer account, also associated with *MyCompany Ltd*. My client has just created a brand new Apple Developer account, associated with *HisCompany Ltd*. He's added me as an Admin on this account, and my next task is to create an iTunes Connect app record for an app to be released by *HisCompany Ltd.*, and start the process of submitting an app to the App Store. However, whilst my Apple Developer account has a relationship with *HisCompany Ltd.*, my iTunesConnect account does not, meaning - afaict - that I cannot create the requisite iTunes Connect app record to start the process.

How can I associate my iTunesConnect account with his *HisCompany Ltd.*'s developer account, and/or create this iTunes Connect app record?

Or does the client have to do it maybe?

I don't know, and the docs haven't helped me thus far.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Answer seems to be: yes, the client has to do it. Only the owner - the “Legal (Team Agent)” - of *HisCompany Ltd.* can add Admin level users to her or his iTunesConnect account, as hinted at here: https://developer.apple.com/support/itunes-connect/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13

Answer (score 1):

Your client will need to add your Apple ID to both https://developer.apple.com/ (ADC) as well as to https://itunesconnect.apple.com (ITC) - both times as Admins. Then you can setup the record for the new app on ADC and then create the app over at ITC and upload it there.